# CSV data comes in single line on uploading on SFTP

Tags: file-upload, ftp, sftp

We have a csv file with | symbol as a separator. The data in the file spans across multiple lines e.g.

123|2323|2323|23232|2323|232323|2323|2323|2323|3434
1213|323|2323|2323|3|323|323|2323|3434|3434|3434
3434|34343|434

But once we upload this file on an sftp and download there, it shows the data in a single line. And if we download it at our end, it shows the correct data i.e. as it was uploaded.

Does someone know what could be the reason & how to fix it?

Comment: what OS are you on and which is the server on? They could have different definitions for newline characters.

Comment: @Darkwater, thanks for your interest. I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the reason, actually it was being uploaded in the text mode, once we changed it to Binary mode. It worked fine.